# What exactly do power plans do in Windows 7?

Tags: power-management

What do power plans do on a desktop PC? My computer has Balanced, AMD Power Plan, Power saver and High performance. When going to change settings, the only things to change are the display timeout and sleep timer. That got me wondering, what does it do under the hood? I know there are advanced settings, but I'm not too comfortable changing them, so can someone explain them to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default power plans try to give you a balance of good performance and good battery life based on essentially guesses as to how most people use their systems. Create your own plans which best suites your needs because you know well how you want to use the system .

Most of the settings are self explanatory ,we will see some of them

Turn off the display: Ask yourself when you will taking pauses, and it depends on your concentration level as well .Shorten the length of time before Windows dims and turns off the display
Put the computer to sleep: The ‘sleep’ mode for computers is conceptually similar to sleep as we experience; it’s a low-power state that preserves everything in memory. It’s better the computer go to sleep than sit and idle using considerably more power. 
Adjust plan brightness: This will vary depending on the computer; consider the display is the number one consumer of power  I consider brightness sufficient if I can read text. Be as conservative as possible here. It depends on you .

In the advanced settings you can take care of the following

Turn off or remove devices that you aren't using ,make sure this is helping you rather than putting you in trouble .

Wireless Adapter Settings : leave this at ‘Maximum Performance’ when plugged in,If you notice connectivity problems while unplugged, change this setting up to the next level from wherever it’s set (e.g. Low to Medium).

Sleep :hybrid sleep is useful for desktops whereas you can disable this if you are using laptops

Power buttons and lid : You are the best person to decide these based on your needs. Choose wisely

Processor power management > System cooling policy: this should always be ‘Active’ for plugged in; for battery , If you are putting this to passive ,the cooling fan wil be off nad it will make your processor to heat up that may lead to overheating

Battery : These are self-explanatory; If you have an older battery , it doesn’t hold the charge as it did when new so 10% is not enough warning, you can set it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Different power plans change the settings also available through the Advanced Power Settings mentioned in Prince Nnamdi's answer. The quick selection is simply a shortcut to set multiple settings at once. Sometimes vendors add their own that are tuned in for their own hardware.

But in general, the settings adjust things like:

- When the screen goes to sleep mode
- When the hard drive goes to sleep
- Maximum screen brightness
- Maximum CPU speed (and minimum)
- Disabling wireless connections under conditions
- Suspending USB connections